# How to work with an array of bits in tarantool?

Tags: tarantool

I want to work with an array of bits in tarantool. I need redis-like operations: setbit, getbit and bitcount. Is it possible in tarantool?

Answer (score 1):

Use built-in module [bit](http://bitop.luajit.org/):

```
tarantool> bit
---
- rol: 'function: builtin#70'
  rshift: 'function: builtin#68'
  ror: 'function: builtin#71'
  bswap: 'function: builtin#66'
  bxor: 'function: builtin#74'
  bor: 'function: builtin#73'
  arshift: 'function: builtin#69'
  bnot: 'function: builtin#65'
  tobit: 'function: builtin#64'
  lshift: 'function: builtin#67'
  tohex: 'function: builtin#75'
  band: 'function: builtin#72'
...
```